# Why dynamic input fields don't take values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am adding rows using java script functions by taking input and showing data into input text fields.

I am using this datepicker https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.

When I input time the only first value of time is copied into input fields while rest two value are copied but time value is not copied.

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">
<h1>Simple example of dynamically adding rows with jQuery</h1>

<form method="post">
<div id="itemRows">

Item quantity: <input type="text" name="add_qty" size="4" /> Item name: <input type="text" name="add_name" />Time:<input type="text" id="time" name="time"   />



(This row will not be saved unless you click on "Add row" first)

<input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row" /> 

    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save Changes"></p>
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
rowNum ++;
var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item quantity: <input type="text"        name="qty[]" size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'">Time<input type="text" id="time" name="time[]" size="4" value="'+frm.time.value+'" > Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
frm.add_qty.value = '';
frm.add_name.value = '';
frm.time.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: English sentences start with a capital and end with a "." ."I" is always capital on English.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate dynamic textbox with id and with date picker so you need to call one function for init datepicker on that text like below

```
$('input').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker();

function addRow(frm) 
{
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'">Time<input type="text" id="time'+rowNum+'" name="time[]" size="4" value="'+frm.time.value+'" > Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';

    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
    frm.time.value = '';
    $('#time'+rowNum).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker();
}
```

In above function i add one id to time textbox and call bootstrap datepicker to init date on that textbox.

See working demo here

http://plnkr.co/edit/P0ZQsAjDJAXyJGs9kvT3?p=preview

Comment: i have initialised datepicker in another function and its working,but the problem is time value is appended only in first row and not in the following rows , and datepicker is working fine

Comment: In dynamic created time textbox you need to show datepicker am i right?

Comment: No time picker is working fine but when I select time through time picker time  is not appended to 2,3..  rows but is appended only in first row you can see in image only first row has time rest don't have

Comment: I edit my answer please see working plnkr link. hope that is help you